# Is there a difference between "у меня болит голова" and "у меня головная боль"?

Tags: выбор-слова

I've been trying to prevent my Russian from rusting by going through Duolingo in both directions (Russian for English speakers and English for Russian speakers). I found "I have a headache" being consistently translated as "у меня болит голова" in the Russian lessons, and as "у меня головная боль" in the English lessons.

I gather that they have the same meaning, but are they exact synonyms or this there a nuance between them? Maybe one of them is more childish or more casual or something else?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The other answers correctly stated that "болит голова" is more common and "головная боль" is more formal. I'd like to add that in addition to the literal meaning, "головная боль"/"headache" can be used figuratively, as in an annoying, persistent problem. In this figurative use, "головная боль" is correct.

Comment: Actually both expressions can be used figuratively, again with the verbal phrase being more colloquial (*а об этом пусть у него голова болит*= but that's his problem).

Answer (score 7):

«У меня головная боль» is more formal. You might say it during a doctor's appointment.

The adjective «головной» is very rare. Off the top of my head, I can only recall two fixed phrases that contain it: «головная боль» (*headache*) and «головной офис» (*main office, headquarters*).

Comment: Also *головной убор*(headdress), *головной мозг*(brain), *головное ведомство* (parent institution)

Answer (score 3):

У меня болит голова and у меня головная боль are synonymous, but in everyday life the most common way to say this is у меня болит голова.